# Is there any public ArcGIS Server that uses HTTP authentication that can be used for testing?

Tags: arcgis-server, authentication

I have the requirement to connect to an ArcGIS service that use Http authentication, currently I do not have an EDN or Server license to setup an environment like that. 
Are there any public server that can provide this services with some kind of free user?

Comment: Why doesn't the organization imposing the requirement provide the resources to meet the requirement?

Comment: The same question was asked to the team leader and project manager....I'm still waiting for an answer